# Any incidence of Elasticsearch data loss during query

Tags: elasticsearch, rdbms

I am evaluating Elasticsearch for storing few billions of documents of same schema. Each of my document has 50+ attributes like username, city, address, country, favorite_book, favorite_food etc. My teammate raised a concern that when you query username = 'ram' then elasticsearch may not return exact number of documents. E.g. There could be 10,000,817 documents with username = 'ram' but elasticsearch may return only 10,000,000 documents as total hits. Is this kind of data loss possible in elasticsearch queries? If the data is too sparse then is it possible ? I am not talking about the cases like node going down or shard is not available. My question is when cluster health is green and all shards are available. This fear is mainly because elasticsearch is search engine and I am trying to use it as RDBMS.

I am not using full text search and all string fields are mapped as not_analyzed. I am not using score queries.

Thanks. I searched few top questions on elastic forum and stackoverflow but cannot spot any such reported incidence.

Comment: First, it would be interesting to know where your teammate got this information from, or if it's just pure speculation.

Comment: Its fear. Sometimes web search engines show broken search results. Trying to understand that if elasticsearch keeps index updated even after few updates on documents.

Comment: Forget about fear ;-) Spin up a small cluster (one node to start), load it with some data and do some testing, you'll get better insights on how it behaves under normal conditions.

Comment: I do have one cluster and I think it is giving me positive results but as the data generated their is using a random data generator program, it is difficult to verify. Reason for fear is due to some of the issues other users of elasticsearch raised about data loss during data indexing.

Comment: As with any other technology, things can also go wrong with Elasticsearch, and they will. However, if serious efforts are put at the right place to build something solid, then issues can be mitigated pretty easily. At this point, I'd say that your question is simply too broad to be answered since it depends on too many unknowns and speculations.

Comment: To narrow my question: I am asking about where clause that is put in elasticsearch queries. My where clause will be like username=ram & city=LA & country=USA & joiningdate between 01-01-2016 and 01-06-2016. I understand that there are few cardinality algorithms which have trade-offs for aggs queries.

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing such a complaint. I've seen something similar though, with different runs of the same query for older versions of Elasticsearch. Basically, the shards (primary and replica) went for whatever reason unsynced. Thing that shouldn't happen and when it did it was most likely because of a split brain situation. But, I repeat, this was for older ES versions, ie 1.4.x.